Custom `arara` engine in TexShop for music tools
In a related thread, I asked for help setting up a TexShop engine for MusixTex. At the suggestion of @Alan Munn, I would now like to create an 'arara' engine that will accomplish at least the following processes from within TexShop without resorting to the terminal.

Process the MusixTex "three pass system" using \usepackage{musixtex} in a LaTeX document, producing a PDF output in TexShop.
Process a plain TeX file containing MusixTex code, producing a PDF output in TexShop.
Process an M-Tx file, producing a PDF output in TexShop.
Process a Latex input with lilypond-book script to render LilyPond code in a LaTeX document (PDF output in TexShop).

I already have a TexShop .engine script for #1,
#!/bin/bash

PATH=$PATH:/Library/TeX/texbin


pdflatex "$1" --file-line-error --synctex=1
musixflx "$1"
pdflatex "$1" --file-line-error --synctex=1

but what I need help figuring out is how to create an arara engine that will allow me to run these various processes via the use of arara "rules." I had originally envisioned creating a separate engine for each process, but it seems that the automation features of arara would be a superior way to use TexShop with these programs.

There’s already a Lilypond engine in TexShop. Check in the Inactive folder and move it to the Engines folder.
